# RestKit view all headers for RKObjectRequestOperation

Tags: ios, restkit

How can I get all the headers that are set for the RKObjectRequestOperation. I need to view the headers as there is something strange happening after a user has logged out, and want to view all headers before the operation starts.

Also is restkit caching authorization headers? I've tried setting the value in the manual request to an empty string and used `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient clearAuthorizationHeader];` to try clearing them, but the server is still receiving the Authorization header.

Comment: Use Charles to verify what is actually sent

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Wain. I couldn't get Charles to read my local. But solved the issue, there was a session that was still active. Removed sessions from the server since it is RESTful anyway and shouldn't be there and that solved the problems. You have any links that might help us setup Charles with eclipse? I did a google search but the few links that did come up didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can print `defaultHeaders` to check what is actually set in headers.

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] HTTPClient] defaultHeaders]
```